# Marketing Cloud tracking tag implementation with Tag Commander

Tags: marketing-cloud, tag

Has anyone implemented the Marketing Cloud tracking Tag with Tag Commander?
If yes what would be the steps to follow? 
My need it pretty classic, I would like to be able to track the wishlists of known customers (those navigating the website after a click through the newsletter), abandoned carts, and also the product pages visited.
Would you have any advice on the step to follows? I've checked the documentation but I'm unclear on few points.
For example how to match incoming traffic coming from newsletters to Marketing Cloud customer database?

Any help/insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Greg